# Specifying which Launcher to use

Tags: spring, spring-boot

how can you specify a different Launcher to use. I want to use the PropertiesLauncher added in M5 release

I tried by modifying the mainfest file to force it to use the PropertiesLauncher class and it kind of works but throws this error ]

```
$ java -jar hdfspub-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Oct 28, 2013 12:42:44 PM org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher initializeProperties

INFO: Found: application.properties
Oct 28, 2013 12:42:44 PM org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher initializePaths
INFO: Nested archive paths: [lib/]

Oct 28, 2013 12:42:44 PM org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher getClassPathArchives
INFO: Adding classpath entries from lib/

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No 'Start-Class' manifest entry specified
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.Archive.getMainClass(Archive.java:52)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.getMainClass(PropertiesLauncher.java:298)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:343) So it seems like it fails on including jars that dont have Start-Class specified ..

Comment: This is a nice question, did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes I used the maven configuration from the below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use "java -jar ..." it looks in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF for a Main-Class attribute. There is nothing Spring related to that. If you build the jar with spring-boot-tools then the Main-Class is guessed, and I don't think there was any support in M5 for overriding that. In recent snapshots you can specify the "layout" as ZIP, e.g.

```
apply plugin: "spring-boot"
springBoot {
  layout = 'ZIP'
}
```

or in Maven

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <layout>ZIP</layout>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify the launcher without rebuilding (let's say <layout>ZIP</layout> wasn't specified).

Comment: You should be able to use the classpath (instead of `java -jar`) and include the main class on the command line, instead of having it read from the manifest.